# (AS3) Update start coordinates in a Tween

Tags: actionscript-3

I wanted to try implement the Arrcordion Menu at http://www.freeactionscript.com/2009/10/simple-accordion-menu/ using AS3 Tween Class.

So i'm using 2 screen MovieClips, positioned at the right side of the stage and when I click on a screen, it will tween to the left.

Here is my code

```
import fl.transitions.Tween;
import fl.transitions.easing.*;
import fl.transitions.TweenEvent;

var second:int = 1;
var x1:int = screen01.x; //screen01.x = 430
var x2:int = screen02.x; // screen02.x = 470

var Tween1:Tween = new Tween(screen01, "x", Regular.easeOut, x1, 40, second, true);
var Tween2:Tween = new Tween(screen02, "x", Regular.easeOut, x2, 470, second, true);
var Tween3:Tween = new Tween(screen01, "x", Regular.easeOut, x1, 40, second, true);
var Tween4:Tween = new Tween(screen02, "x", Regular.easeOut, x2, 80, second, true);

screen01.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickHandler, false, 0, true);
screen02.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickHandler, false, 0, true);

function clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void{

        x1 = screen01.x;
        x2 = screen02.x;

        if(event.target == screen01)
        {
            Tween1.start()
            Tween2.start()              
        }
        else if(event.target == screen02)
        {   
            Tween3.start()
            Tween4.start()
        }
}
```

But why is it when i click screen01 it tweens to the left. Then I click screen02 and screen01 returns to 430 before they both tween.
When I trace x1 and x2 within the MouseEvent, the coordinates have been updated so why doesn't screen01 stay at 40 while screen02 tweens to the left? 
Also if screen02 is open, when I click on screen01, both screens return to their original positions 430 and 470 and screen01 tweens.

I can assume that my problem is Tween1,Tween2,Tween3 and Tween4 start coordinates aren't changing after it's initialised. Is there a way to update the start coordinates for the 4 tweens so that they equal x1 and x2?

Answer (score 0):

You can kill() the tween and start another. The object is already partially moved and will continue from that point on. If you want the movement to be proportional, then use a timer and use the ratio between currentTime and totalTime (something like that) then just change the distance you multiply the ratio to.